# What is a preferred way to access application domain logic from a BroadcastReceiver in Android?

Tags: android, singleton

I have an Android application, which makes use of an AlarmManager to schedule events. When an Intent from AlarmManager is received, domain logic has to do some work, which includes accessing a DB and broadcasting intents. Currently I use a Singleton to access the domain logic from a BroadcastReceiver (registered in the manifest) in a way:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Singleton.getInstance().onAlarmFired();
    }
}
```

This Singleton is used in activities and services in the same way.
It works fine, but Singleton is considered to be an anti-pattern, and I would like to cover code with tests, so I am looking for a different solution.

Now the question is wouldn't it be better to use a Service instead of this Singleton? Like this:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        startService(new Intent(intent.getAction());
    }
}
```

What are the benefits and drawbacks? And what will be the best way to communicate with the service from an Activity? I am thinking about binding to the service in MyApplication and provide reference to activities and services using getApplication() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now the question is wouldn't it be better to use a Service instead of this Singleton?

Yes, very much so.  The prime directive when it comes to `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive()` is respond spend as little time inside the metod as possible because that execution is being done on the main thread and if the `BroadcastReceiver` is alive for more than 10 seconds it quickly becomes a candidate for death ([see the docs for more](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive%28android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent%29)).

Calling a `Service` to do the work instead is a perfect replacement implementation and returns from `onReceive()` very quickly.

Depending on what your `Service` is doing you can bind it to an `Activity` to call methods on it, or simply continue to use `Intents` to send data back and forth (you might want to take a look at `LocalBroadcastManager` in the support library for the latter case).

> I am thinking about binding to the service in MyApplication and provide reference to activities and services using getApplication() method

I would strongly urge against this.  I would consider using the `Application` class at all in many cases also an anti-pattern.  It's lifecycle is not easier to keep tabs on than a created Singleton.  Instead, if you want to bind the `Service` in order to use it, bind it to any `Activity` that wants access while it is currently in the foreground.

**EDIT:** To your question about System Services

System Services and Application Services are very different; System Services aren't even services at all (in the SDK definition of the word).  They are Singleton objects that run inside the `system_server` process, where they are protected from disruption, and talk to the manager objects you have access to using AIDL and IPC.

A Singleton in your application does not have the same luxury.  If your application crashes, Android cannot assist in restarting your obhect.  But more importantly, since it is not a registered system component, Android will not recognize your application as doing valid background work if you are executing code in the background here and you will be a more likely target for low memory killing if your application is not in the foreground.

So, while technically using a Singleton will work, moving your code into a traditional `Service` is considered best practice and will give you the most benefit from the platform itself.

Comment: an AsyncTask could be spun off from the singleton.  So what then is the advantage of the service?  That you have to bind to it?

Comment: That it's a life cycle managed component of the system.  It can be started when needed, stopped when not, and even restarted by the system I'd it crashes while running.

Comment: @Devunwired I wanted to to access my service in a same way I get access to system services:
SomeManager = (SomeManager)context.getSystemService("service_name");

in this case SomeManager is a part of the framework, and it has already bind to the service. So manager simply redirects calls to the service. I wanted to achieve roughly the same, but since I cannot modify the context, I wanted to use MyApplication for that.

Comment: From the perspective of `onReceive()` that would still create the same issue.  Accessing the object directly still means all that code gets executed inside of the `BroadcatReceiver`...keeping it alive.  Calling `startService()` hands the work off to another component and returns, which is "the Android way".  I also added some more notes about your System Service question.